# What does "CMD + <" do in AZERTY keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

What does <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> do in AZERTY keyboard layout? I'm trying to assign it to a program using apptivate, but it keeps telling me it is already assigned to a system-wide shortcut.

I've been looking around in the keyboard prefpane, but nothing uses this shortcut yet. I've also tried to use the shortcut in many different applications, but most of the time it does absolutely nothing, with an occasional error beep.

What can I do?

Comment: how are you listing the shortcut? CMD + < or CMD + SHIFT + ,

Comment: I've got an AZERTY keyboard.. so `<` is actually a key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the shortcut is meant to go to settings of what ever program is running in the foreground (it will be the program in the upper left corner of your screen). However you can customize your shortcut settings in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts

Comment: Settings shortcut is `CMD + i`. For example `CMD + <` says is used for `Windows -> Next Window` (don't know the actual english equivalent, i'm using a german Mac OS)

Comment: German `cmd + <` has the english equivalent of cmd + ` (backtick).

Comment: ok turning of `CMD` + ` worked!

Answer (score 1):

On my Swedish system, <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd><</kbd> switches between windows in the same application, at least for some applications.

Comment: ok, but the problem remains. How to turn it of if it isn't in the keyboards prefpane.